# What is the language the kids are speaking at the end of Star Wars: The Last Jedi (conlang or real?)

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

What is the language the kids are speaking at the end of Star Wars: The Last Jedi?  Is it a real language, or a conlang, and if a conlang, is it "based" on a real language?

Comment: No help from the audio described version or the closed captions. It just says *"Speaking alien dialect"*

Answer (score 6):

This is [*Cantonican*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cantonican), according to [Star Wars Kids](https://archive.ph/qftPd#selection-1419.0-1419.61), an (alas defunct) Lucasfilm-owned YouTube channel.

> Cantonican was a language spoken on the planet Cantonica. It was
> spoken by the human stable hand Oniho Zaya, who used it while
> retelling the story of the Jedi Master Luke Skywalker at the Battle of
> Crait.
>
> <sub><sup>Cantonican: Wookieepedia</sup></sub>